# how to save .fmx file (oracle forms) deployed on a website

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Is there any way to save the oracle forms(3-tier) .fmx file running from a server, accessed using a web browser..

what i am getting is some tags containing the .fmx file location . on accessing those files i get the .fmx running. i need dump of the .fmx

Following is the code received by the browser:

```
<!-- Forms applet definition (start) -->
<OBJECT classid="clsid:CAFECAFE-0013-0001-0022-ABCDEFABCDEF"
        codebase="/forms/jinitiator/jinit.exe#Version=1,3,1,22"
        WIDTH="800"
        HEIGHT="600"
        HSPACE="0"
        VSPACE="0">
<PARAM NAME="TYPE"       VALUE="application/x-jinit-applet;version=1.3.1.22">
<PARAM NAME="CODEBASE"   VALUE="/forms/java">
<PARAM NAME="CODE"       VALUE="oracle.forms.engine.Main" >
<PARAM NAME="ARCHIVE"    VALUE="frmall_jinit.jar,JCalendarJinit.jar,jcalendar.jar,jacob.jar,frmwebutil.jar,icons.jar" > 
<PARAM NAME="serverURL" VALUE="/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=/forms/frmservlet?form=PR_SC_3T_LOGIN_EDB.fmx&acceptLanguage=en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4">
<PARAM NAME="networkRetries" VALUE="0">
<PARAM NAME="serverArgs" 
       VALUE="escapeParams=true module=PR_SC_3T_LOGIN_EDB.fmx userid=  sso_userid=%20 sso_formsid=formsApp_appserv5.vsp.org_E90504F17EA811DFBFFD1B9BE00D2215 sso_subDN= sso_usrDN= debug=no host= port= buffer_records=no debug_messages=no array=no obr=no query_only=no quiet=yes render=no record= tracegroup= log= term=">
<PARAM NAME="separateFrame" VALUE="True">
<PARAM NAME="splashScreen"  VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="background"  VALUE="NO">
<PARAM NAME="lookAndFeel"  VALUE="Oracle">
<PARAM NAME="colorScheme"  VALUE="teal">
<PARAM NAME="serverApp" VALUE="default">
<PARAM NAME="logo" VALUE="NO">
<PARAM NAME="imageBase" VALUE="DocumentBase">
<PARAM NAME="formsMessageListener" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="recordFileName" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="EndUserMonitoringEnabled" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="EndUserMonitoringURL" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="heartbeat" VALUE="">
<COMMENT> 
<EMBED SRC="" PLUGINSPAGE="/forms/jinitiator/us/jinit_download.htm" 
        TYPE="application/x-jinit-applet;version=1.3.1.22" 
        java_codebase="/forms/java" 
        java_code="oracle.forms.engine.Main" 
        java_archive="frmall_jinit.jar,JCalendarJinit.jar,jcalendar.jar,jacob.jar,frmwebutil.jar,icons.jar" 
        WIDTH="800"
        HEIGHT="600" 
        HSPACE="0"
        VSPACE="0"
        serverURL="/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=/forms/frmservlet?form=PR_SC_3T_LOGIN_EDB.fmx&acceptLanguage=en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4"
        networkRetries="0"
        serverArgs="escapeParams=true module=PR_SC_3T_LOGIN_EDB.fmx userid=  sso_userid=%20 sso_formsid=formsApp_appserv5.vsp.org_E90504F17EA811DFBFFD1B9BE00D2215 sso_subDN= sso_usrDN= debug=no host= port= buffer_records=no debug_messages=no array=no obr=no query_only=no quiet=yes render=no record= tracegroup= log= term="
        separateFrame="True"
        splashScreen=""
        background="NO"
        lookAndFeel="Oracle"
        colorScheme="teal"
        serverApp="default"
        logo="NO"
        imageBase="DocumentBase"
        formsMessageListener=""
        recordFileName=""
        EndUserMonitoringEnabled=""
        EndUserMonitoringURL=""
        heartBeat=""
>
<NOEMBED> 
</COMMENT> 
</NOEMBED></EMBED> 
</OBJECT>
<!-- Forms applet definition (end) -->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

Comment: The fmx location is described in application server, in environment variables, under variable FORMS_PATH. I doubt that you can get them easy :) I think you have to have access to application server to get it.

Comment: I hope the next question isn't "now I have the fmx files, but they won't open in form builder..."

Answer (score 0):

Using .fmx files:

- Cannot edit or view the code written.
- Running offline cannot be useful is some case: if the form uses queries and needs to be connected to the database.
- Maybe the main reason why using fmx files, is too use the same form on multiple endpoint within an intra-network

For the fmx on the server, you can try to access that link /forms/frmservlet?form=PR_SC_3T_LOGIN_EDB.fmx and try to download it from the server.

Hope it helps you.